# Cin making me enter twice

Tags: validation, c++11, input

I have the code below to trap the users.  The problem is when the while is triggered because of the user entering in a character or string, it makes the user enter the data twice before accepting it.  I'm not quite sure why it's doing that and was hoping someone could explain it to me.  thanks!

```
    bool valid_entry = false;
while (!valid_entry) {
    cin >> distanceTraveled;
    while ((!(cin >> distanceTraveled)) ||(distanceTraveled==0)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "ERROR:  invalid Entry.   Try again.\n\nHow far did ya go? ";
        cin.clear();
        cin >> distanceTraveled;
    }

        valid_entry = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're asking them twice!

```
cin >> distanceTraveled;
while ((!(cin >> distanceTraveled)) ...
```

Try:

```
// assuming that distanceTraveled == 0 is invalid input
while ((cin >> distanceTraveled) && (distanceTraveled == 0))
```

And if you're trying to clear out any other input they entered on a line, you can use `getline` instead.

```
std::string junk;
std::getline(cin, junk);
std::cout << "ERROR:  invalid Entry.   Try again.\n\nHow far did ya go? ";
```

So the code would now look like this:

```
std::string junk;
std::cout << "How far did you go? ";
while ((cin >> distanceTraveled) && (distanceTraveled == 0)) 
{
    std::getline(cin, junk);
    std::cout << "ERROR:  invalid Entry.   Try again.\n\nHow far did ya go? ";
}
```

Comment: @Melissagoodall: You're new to it is all. Getting the order of asking for input and validating it correct can be really confusing (even for more experienced developers)